# How to update item from $scope ng-repeat after saving using $resource

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service, angular-resource

I have an angular view which displays a list of items and for each there are two buttons that set each campaign on pause/start. I know it's a very basic problem with angular $resource, but I can't update the item on success $start (in the success callback I can't access anything related to the item).

```
function CampaignsListCtrl($scope, Campaign, $resource) {
    $scope.campaigns = Campaign.query();

    $scope.startCampaign = function () {
        var c = new Campaign(this.campaign);
        c.status = 1;
        c.$start(function success(response) {
               //here I'd like to update the value but can't access the item.
               //for example this.campaign.status = 1 doesn't work
               //how can I access the ng-repeat item to update it on success $start?
               //the response represents the updated Object

               console.log (response);

        }, function error (response) {
           console.log (response)
        });
    }

    $scope.pauseCampaign = function () {
        var c = new Campaign(this.campaign);
        c.status = 0;
        c.$pause(function success(response) {
               console.log (response);

        }, function error (response) {
           console.log (response)
        });
    }

}
//// and Campaign is defined as factory
mongoAPI.
factory('Campaign', ['$resource', '$http', function($resource, $http) {
        var actions = {
            'start': {method:'POST'},                           
            'pause': {method:'POST'}                 
        }
        var res = $resource('/api/campaign.js',{}, actions)
        return res;
}]);
```

and in views I have:

```
<div ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns">
     <button type="button" ng-show="campaign.status==0" ng-click="startCampaign(campaign)" class="btn"><i class="icon-play"></i></button>
     <button type="button" ng-show="campaign.status==1" ng-click="pauseCampaign(campaign)" class="btn"><i class="icon-pause"></i></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a closure/scope related question, not Angular itself. Inside the success handler, `this` is not the scope anymore, so there is no way to access `this.campaign`. You actually can solve this problem in a bunch of ways.

The simples, I belive, is to receive the `campaign` as parameter and just reference it from there:

You already have this in your HTML:

```html
ng-click="startCampaign(campaign)"
```

So receive and use it:

```js
$scope.startCampaign = function (campaign) {
    var c = new Campaign(campaign);
    c.$start(function success(response) {
      campaign.status = 1;
    },
    ...
};
```